# How to keep Switch default case as original function?

Tags: function-construction, conditional

For example of below Switch function.

```
In[]:= Module[{f},
 f[x_] := Switch[x, 1, 2, 3, 4];
 {f[1], f[3], f[x]}
 ]

Out[]= {2, 4, Switch[x,
  1, 2,
  3, 4]}
```

`f[1]` and `f[3]` is evaluated as defined, but since it doesn't define a default case, the original input seems to be a more natural result, and more friendly one.

Is it possible to define the above `f[x]` so the output becomes:

```
Out[]= {2, 4, f[x]}
```

I tried to use `Unevaluated[f[x]]`, but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, x]

Block[{f}, f[x_] := Switch[x, 1, 2, 3, 4, _, Defer[f][x]];
 {f[1], f[3], f[5], f[x]}]
```

> ```
> {2, 4, f[5], f[x]}
> ```

Answer (score 6):

```
Block[{f}, 
 f[x_] := With[{res = Switch[x, 1, 2, 3, 4, _, $Failed]}, res /; res =!= $Failed];
 {f[1], f[3], f[x]}
]

(*{2, 4, f[x]}*)
```